# How uninstall a program using the UninstallString found in REGEDIT with CMD/MSIExec?

Tags: windows

I found the registry key `UninstallString` while trying to uncover the path to an uninstaller. This was found in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

The `UninstallString` Contained: `MsiExec.exe /X{DBB43649-A97A-41A2-80E4-20E1D2340EBC}`

I interpret this as Windows using the `MsiExec.exe` with flag `/X` on path `{DBB43649-A97A-41A2-80E4-20E1D2340EBC}`.

However, when I try the command in CMD(as admin) it does not find the uninstall. When I run Program files, program files finds wherever this MSI is behind the scenes and uninstalls it so Windows knows where it is ultimately.

My main goal was to get a script created to uninstall software for multiple Windows Servers.
Is there a way to find the uninstaller for a program so it can be uninstalled via CMDs MSIExec?

Thank you for any assistance and direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{DBB43649-A97A-41A2-80E4-20E1D2340EBC}`is the ID of the program, no the file or path. You could look the application up at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID` or in powerhell with`get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name`.

However, `MsiExec.exe /X {DBB`(...) should always work. If you get a 'File not found' error, check if msiexec is in your path.

Comment: Thank you! That led me to think about what I was missing. I needed to run CMD as an admin. The `UninstallString` from `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` had the command that I could run to uninstall from CMD.